# jquery onclick by class name - how to

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have: `<a class='category' href='view.php?category=1'>category</a>`

i do: `$("a.category").click(function(){alert("dsafdfad")})`

and nothing happens??

start("view.php?");
    posts("view.php?");

```
function start(link){
    $("#country ul").load(link+"mode=start",function(){
    $("#country a").click(function(){
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        category(link+"&");
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
        });
    });
}

function start2(link){
    $("#country ul").load(link+"mode=start",function(){
    $("#country a").click(function(){
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
        });
    });
}

function posts(link){
    $("#posts").load(link+"mode=posts",function(){
    $("a.country").click(function(){
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        category(link+"&");
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
        });
    $("a.category").click(function(){
        $("#category").css("display","none");
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        start2(link+"&");
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
    });
    });
}

function category(link){
    $("#category ul").load(link+"mode=verNav",function(){
        $("#category").css("display","block");
        $("#category a").click(function(){
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question (add the html). Do you have an a tag with a class category?

Comment: is your event handler wrapped in a document ready handler ... otherwise JQuery can't bind the event correctly because the dom has not yet loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that the jQuery line is called when the element is already been created and present in the HTML DOM. In other words, do it during `$(document).ready()` in page head

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Here.
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

or put the script at bottom of the page body, *after* the elements of interest.

```
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        // Here.
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: i do. these are all inside load callback function

Comment: why dont you just do $('.category') and try that without the tag specific class?

Comment: @daniel: this gives nothing to work with then. Post an SSCCE or jsfiddle.net demo link which reproduces exactly your problem. Probably the "load callback function" is just bogus or expecting data which isn't in DOM yet at that point.

Comment: $("#posts").load(link+"mode=posts",function(){
    $("a.country").click(function(){
        var link=encodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
        category(link+"&");
        posts(link+"&");
        return false;
        });

Comment: like i said when i do #div a it works just fine. i suppose dom is loaded

Answer (score 1):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/EYchy/).  A few things to check:

- Are you clicking the link?
- Are you [waiting until the DOM loads](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) before binding to the click event?
- Is jQuery loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have "alert" as local variable or overriding the jQuery "$".

Comment: this is a fairly unlikely scenario as he described that it worked when he changed the tag selector ...